# Rails autocomplete textfield won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

Followed this guide by railscasts to setup autocompletion on collection_select.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7yhPlIehFA
In my example I'm trying to create a chatroom with a game related.

**MODEL**

```
belongs_to :game
validates :game, presence: true

def game_name
    game.try(:name)
end

def game_name=(name)
    self.game = Game.where(name: name).first_or_create if name.present?
end
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
def create
    @room = current_user.chatrooms.build(room_params)

    if @room.save
        redirect_to @room
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def room_params
    params.require(:chatroom).permit(:title, :description, :game_id)
end
```

**HTML**

```
<%= simple_form_for @room do |f| %>
  <p class="ftitle">Chatroom title</p>
  <%= f.input :title, label: false %>
  <p class="ftitle">Chatroom description</p>
  <%= f.input :description, label: false %>
  <p class="ftitle">Select related game</p>
  <%= f.text_field :game_name, data: { autocomplete_source: Game.order(:name).map(&:name) } %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

It works fine until I try to create a chatroom with a game attached. It won't attach the game_id as a game. Not sure why.
Thanks.

Comment: How are you creating the chatroom? Could you add that code? And the actual controller method rather than just the strong params method?

Comment: Added the create method and the form for. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to link the game based on name seems quite brittle and open to future abuse.

However if that's really what you want to do, add `:game_name` to the `.permit` method in room_params.

It would be more robust to pass through an ID here, rather than plain text.